# Animating a pulsing UILabel?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I am trying to animate the color the the text on a UILabel to pulse from: [Black] to [White] to [Black] and repeat.

```
- (void)timerFlash:(NSTimer *)timer {
[[self navTitle] setTextColor:[[UIColor whiteColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.0]];
[UIView animateWithDuration:1
                      delay:0 
                    options:UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction 
                 animations:^{[[self navTitle] setTextColor:[[UIColor whiteColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:1.0]];} 
                 completion:nil];
}
```

.

```
[self setFadeTimer:[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1 target:self selector:@selector(timerFlash:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES]];
```

Firstly I am not sure of my method, my plan (as you can see above) was to set up a animation block and call it using a repeating NSTimer until canceled.

My second problem (as you can see above) is that I am animating from black (alpha 0) to white (alpha 1) but I don't know how to animate back to black again so the animation loops seamlessly

Essentially what I want is the text color to pulse on a UILabel until the user presses a button to continue.

## EDIT_001:

I was getting into trouble because you can't animate [UILabel setColor:] you can however animated [UILabel setAlpha:] so I am going to give that a go.

## EDIT_002:

```
- (void)timerFlash:(NSTimer *)timer {
    [[self navTitle] setAlpha:0.5];
    [UIView animateWithDuration:2 
                          delay:0 
                        options:UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction 
                     animations:^{[[self navTitle] setAlpha:0.9];} 
                     completion:nil];
}
```

This works (BTW: I do want it to stop which is why I hooked it up to a NSTimer so I can cancel that) the only thing is that this animates from midGray to nearWhite and then pops back. Does anyone know how I would animate back from nearWhite to midGray so I get a nice smooth cycle?
[image]

## EDIT_003: (Solution)

The code suggested by Dave DeLong (see below) does indeed work when modified to use the CALayer opacity style attribute:

```
UILabel *navTitle;
@property(nonatomic, retain) UILabel *navTitle;
```

.

```
// ADD ANIMATION
CABasicAnimation *anim = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"opacity"];
[anim setTimingFunction:[CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut]];
[anim setFromValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.5]];
[anim setToValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.0]];
[anim setAutoreverses:YES];
[anim setDuration:0.5];
[[[self navTitle] layer] addAnimation:anim forKey:@"flash"];
```

.

```
// REMOVE ANIMATION
[[[self navTitle] layer] removeAnimationForKey:@"flash"];
```

Comment: I am not 100% convinced that animateWithDuration works with NSTimer as I can't get it to do anything other than pop from one color to the next with no animation.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You could probably do this with a `CAAnimation`.  I just pushed a little demo project I did a while ago onto github.  It shows the olympic logo, and makes the rings fly around to a random location on the screen, then animate back to their original position.  You could *probably* do something very similar, but obviously not using the `position` property.

Here's the basic code to make one of the rings fly around:

```
CABasicAnimation * a = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"position"];
[a setTimingFunction:[CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut]];
[a setFromValue:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:[layer position]]];
[a setToValue:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:[self randomPoint]]];
[a setAutoreverses:YES];
[a setDuration:1.0];
[layer addAnimation:a forKey:nil];
```

Your `fromValue` and `toValue` values would be `CGColorRefs`, and your animation keypath would be different, but the trick here is the `setAutoreverses:YES`.  This will animate from the `fromValue` to the `toValue`, and then back to the `fromValue`.  It's pretty darn handy. :)

https://github.com/davedelong/Demos/blob/master/OlympicRings

---

If that doesn't work (and it might not), then I might just layer two `UILabels` on top of each other and animate their alpha values from 0.0 to 1.0 (or vice versa) at the same time.

Comment: Thank you Dave, I will have a look, I also think that the textColor property of UILabel is not animatable, which is maybe why all I can get is a very non animated poping.

Comment: Hi, I am not that familiar with CoreAnimation, from what I can see the best keyPath value would be "opacity", although I can't find a direct opacity on UILabel or UIView, I might have to try "alpha" but I am not sure how that is going to work. [a setFromValue:[[self navTitle] setAlpha:0.9]]; I am not at my work computer right now, I will try this later ...

Answer (score 9):

If you just want it to happen indefinitely, you can use Dave DeLong's answer, or this:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:1
                      delay:0 
                    options:UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction |
                            UIViewAnimationOptionAutoreverse |
                            UIViewAnimationOptionRepeat
                 animations:^{[[self navTitle] setTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];} 
                 completion:nil];
```

The advantage of using CAAnimation, of course, is that you can remove the animation later; with this, to stop it you'd have to dig down into the CALayer and find the animation to stop it.

You suggested, however, that UILabel.textColor might not be animatable. That's a possibility. If so, you can use this same technique to transition between two UILabels of the different colors and just fade their alpha values.

Comment: Thank you BJ, I do want it to stop which is why I hooked it unto an NSTimer, so I can kill the timer when done. Interesting options though, I will certainly make a note for future reference.

Answer (score 1):

(same as here [Cancel block in UIView animateWithDuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6766034/cancel-block-in-uiview-animatewithduration/12967945#12967945))

I just repeat the animation and kill it after some time with a dispatch block:

```
- (void)animate // Blink a view three times
{
    // We need to stop the animation after a while (0.9 sec)
    dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, 0.9 * NSEC_PER_SEC);
    dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void)
    {
        [view.layer removeAllAnimations];
        view.alpha = 0.0; // Animation clean-up
    });

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.15 // 0.15*6=0.9: It will animate six times (three in reverse)
                          delay:0.0
                        options:UIViewAnimationOptionAutoreverse | UIViewAnimationOptionRepeat
                     animations:^{
                         view.alpha = 1.0; // Animation
                     }
                     completion:NULL];
}
```