# Cancel block in UIView animateWithDuration

Tags: cocoa-touch, objective-c-blocks

```
- (void) startLoading {

    [self blink];
} 

 - (void) blink {  

        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5
                              delay: 0.0
                            options: UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction | UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut
                         animations:^{
                            //animate stuff
                         }
                         completion:^(BOOL finished){
                                 [self blink];    
                         }];

}

- (void) stopLoading {
    //What goes here?
}
```

In my UIView's `initWithFrame`, I build some loader graphics then start the loader animation from `[self startLoading]`.

**The question is now, how do I stop this 'infinite loop'?** or **what goes in the stopLoading or dealloc method to nicely tear everything down?**

When I ignore the fact that a completion block is there and just release my UIView from the super view, everything goes fine for some seconds (more than the 0.5 sec specified) then the app crashes with a message:

> malloc: *** mmap(size=2097152) failed (error code=12)**
>    error: can't allocate region
>   ** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug

I have a breakpoint in malloc_error_break and the culprit is the animation block.

I assume that the UIView was released by being removed from the super view and later on the completion block is executed, having a reference to `self` this is messaging a released object.

I can't find anything in the docs about canceling a 'queued' block.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To cancel, do what you would do with *any* looping operation you want to be able to cancel: set a flag which you check each time before looping. So:

```
- (void) stopLoading {
    kCancel = YES;
}
```

And now your completion block looks like this:

```
completion:^(BOOL finished){
    if (!kCancel)
        [self blink];    
}];
```

`kCancel` could be an ivar, a static global variable, whatever.

Comment: Thanks again Matt. I am slowly getting my head around the animation block thing - especially that it is not 'free' memory/CPU-wise.

Comment: There is an inconvenience with this approach. If you assign NO to flag kCancel before in-flight animation block completed, blink method gets called again. Be careful about it. I wish there was a way to cancel blocks permanently just like cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget, but apparently there is no way.

Comment: minor point, but `kVariable` naming convention should really only be used for truly static values - for example, the standard width of a button in your class, etc. these are usually in fact declared with the `const` argument. -- instead, just use a descriptive variable name.

Comment: I don't know where the `kCancel` variable name came from; it isn't the sort of thing I normally say. In any case the solution I propose here is not the solution I would normally use; I was forced to it by the odd structure of the code in the original question. Normally I would just set directly a property being repeatedly and infinitely animated; this kills the animation.

Answer (score 1):

UIViewAnimationOptionRepeat has magic for u

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5
                      delay: 0.0
                    options: UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction | UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut | UIViewAnimationOptionRepeat
                 animations:^{
                         //animate stuff
                 }
                 completion:^(BOOL finished){
                     NSLog(@"solved ");    
                 }];
```

Comment: Thanks:) however, outside of the animation block in the blink method I increment a variable. If I use the repeat option, the animate block just gets called once (then repeated somewhere else) and the completion block is never called. So as far as I can figure out I need to use the "recursive" approach. Unless I am wrong of course:)

Answer (score 0):

I just repeat the animation and kill it after some time with a dispatch block:

```
- (void)animate // Blink a view three times
{
    // We need to stop the animation after a while (0.9 sec)
    dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, 0.9 * NSEC_PER_SEC);
    dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void)
    {
        [view.layer removeAllAnimations];
        view.alpha = 0.0; // Animation clean-up
    });

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.15 // 0.15*6=0.9: It will animate six times (three in reverse)
                          delay:0.0
                        options:UIViewAnimationOptionAutoreverse | UIViewAnimationOptionRepeat
                     animations:^{
                         view.alpha = 1.0; // Animation
                     }
                     completion:NULL];
}
```